# rsync exclude/include odd behaviour

Tags: linux, rsync

We have tomcat server located at `/opt/tomcat7.0` i want to sync only `logs` directory to remote server, I am trying following `rsync` command with exclude `*` everything and include `logs` but it doesn't syncing anything.

following are tomcat directories (I only want to sync `logs` directory)

```
[rsync@server1]$ ls /opt/tomcat7.0
bin/  conf/  lib/  logs/  temp/  webapps/  work/
```

here is rsync command

```
[rsync@logserver]$ rsync -avz --delete --copy-links --include='logs' --exclude='*' server1:/opt/tomcat7.0 /path/to/destination/.
receiving incremental file list

sent 25 bytes  received 10 bytes  6.36 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to do:

```
rsync -avz --delete --copy-links server1:/opt/tomcat7.0/logs /path/to/destination/.
```

Comment: Because above is just an example i have many tomcat running on server and i am writing script so need to use wildcard.

Comment: this is the solution for the problem described in the question. if in reality you have a problem that is different, you should say so.

Answer (score 0):

The manpage explains why this does not work and what can be done to make it work:

```
   Note that, when using the --recursive (-r) option (which is implied by -a), every subcomponent of  every  path
   is  visited from the top down, so include/exclude patterns get applied recursively to each subcomponent's full
   name (e.g. to include "/foo/bar/baz" the subcomponents "/foo" and  "/foo/bar"  must  not  be  excluded).   The
   exclude  patterns actually short-circuit the directory traversal stage when rsync finds the files to send.  If
   a pattern excludes a particular parent directory, it can render a deeper include pattern  ineffectual  because
   rsync  did  not  descend  through that excluded section of the hierarchy.  This is particularly important when
   using a trailing '*' rule.  For instance, this won't work:

          + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
          + /file-is-included
          - *

   This fails because the parent directory "some" is excluded by the '*' rule, so rsync never visits any  of  the
   files  in  the "some" or "some/path" directories.  One solution is to ask for all directories in the hierarchy
   to be included by using a single rule: "+ */" (put it somewhere before the "- *" rule), and  perhaps  use  the
   --prune-empty-dirs  option.   Another  solution  is to add specific include rules for all the parent dirs that
   need to be visited.  For instance, this set of rules works fine:

          + /some/
          + /some/path/
          + /some/path/this-file-is-found
          + /file-also-included
          - *
```